# Stormpath Custom Data

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, express, stormpath

I requested stormpath user custom data by using

```
res.render('home', {
title: 'home',
user: req.user.customData,


});
```

i expected to receive a json object of custom data but instead  a url ('https://api.stormpath.com/v1/accounts/WvtGbIH3kJ4rEttVF5r9U/customData') was returned. This page does have the custom data i want on it but i cannot request it using an ajax request as it is a https page. What should I do? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the "auto expansion" feature of the library, like this:

```
app.use(stormpath.init(app, {
  expandCustomData: true,
});
```

That will expand the custom data resource for you.  By default it's just a link to the resource, as you've seen.

Comment: I already have that piece of code in my app. I can post custom data to stormpath I just can't retrieve it

Comment: I think i shouldve been using the getCustomData() method. I nearly have it out...

Answer (score 0):

Found the best way to request custom data is to use the getCustomData() method in the route, set the data to a variable and use a get request from the client to request this data as in the sample below:

***Server Js***

```
customData = new Array;


 router.get("/string", function(req, res) {
            req.user.getCustomData(function(err, data) {
                   customData = data.someKey;
                   })

       res.send(customData) /*Returns Empty Arrray*/

 })
router.get("/cdata", function(req, res) {

    res.send(customData) /*Sends Actual Custom Data*/
})
```

***Client Js***

```
var customData = new array

$(document).ready(function() {
        $.get("/string", function(string) {
           /*Tells server to get customData*/ 
        })


    $(document).click(function(){
        if(pleaseCount===0){
        $.get("/cdata", function(data) {

              for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){
              customData.unshift(data[i])
              pleaseCount=pleaseCount+1
        /*Custom data is now stored in client side array*/
        }
      })
   }


    })
```

That's what worked for me anyway. I don't know why someone down-voted the question as this is an acceptable way to retrieve other user information such as name and email by using userName:req.user.userName in the render function and rendering this information to a p. tag in a jade page by using p #{userName}